# More advanced syntax coloring in emacs for Python

Tags: python, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I've been using emacs 24 (built from the git version).  I've started to create a custom theme, but I've noticed that the theming abilities are rather limited, particularly for Python.

I want to be able to assign different colors to things like

- 'Single quoted strings' vs. "Double quoted strings"
- Highlighting of doctests.  So if I have something like

  ```
  def myfunc(x):
      """
      This is the docstring.

      >>> # These are the examples
      >>> print myfunc(x)
      1
      """
      return 1
  ```

  I want the `This is the docstring` to be colored like the string, but I want the `print myfunc()` to be colored like Python code (or at least differently).  For example, in vim, using whatever plugin I have installed, the doctests are colored brown but the strings are colored blue.
- Highlighting docstrings differently than regular strings.
- Coloring of string formatting characters (like `"%s"` or `"%(newstyle_formatting)s"`).
- Better treatment of r, u, or b preceding ' or ".

Any suggestions for one or all of these?

I might add more things here if I think of them.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the description of the variable `font-lock-keywords`. It is possible to add rules based on regexp:s, but also based on functions so you can write code to decide what should be colored and in which color.

Also, you can use `font-lock-add-keywords` to add fontification rules to major modes.